# cannot load mysql2 gem - Load Error - in Ruby File

Tags: ruby, mysql2

When I run the following code in a simple ruby file:

```
require 'mysql2'
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")
```

I get the following response.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.8/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
```

I'm not using this gem in RoR, just pure ruby tinkering for now.
I installed the gem through Homebrew.

### Versions.

gem list mysql2 --> mysql2 (0.4.8)

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for osx10.11 (x86_64)

ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]

Comment: Have you tried downgrade your ruby version, could be the binary files not support ruby 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

create a Gemfile in the same directory as your ruby file

```
# Gemfile

source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "mysql2"
```

Then do `bundle install`

then do `bundle exec ruby my_simple_ruby_file.rb`

Comment: Throws a parsing error ==> There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input - gem "mysql2".  Do I need to specify anything else for the gem file to work or recognize mysql2 gem ?

Comment: Finally managed to run bundler successfully.  However, there's now another  error. "Could not find mysql2-0.4.8 in any of the sources"

Comment: more exactly on bundle exec.  By the way, I changed my ruby version to the latest stable, which is 2.4.1